# Computed property used in local scope causes 'command failed due to signal segmentation fault...?

Tags: swift, swift3

I used the code below in Swift 3 and it worked fine ...

```
func postObject(toCategories categories: [String], object: Object){

    var postedToCategory: Bool {
        if categories.count > 1 {
            return true
        } else if categories[0] != "memes with friends" {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }

    var json = object.jsonified
    json["postedToCategory"] = postedToCategory

    doSomething(dict: json)
}


struct Object {

   var postedToCategory: Bool
   var name: String

   var jsonified: [String: Any] {
       var dict = [String: Any]()
       dict["name"] = self.name
       dict["postedToCategory"] = self.postedToCategory
       return dict
   }


   init(postedToCategory: Bool, name: String){
       self.postedToCategory = postedToCategory
       self.name = name
   }

}
```

But once I updated to Swift 3.1, I kept getting a Swift compile error -> "command failed due to signal: segmentation fault 11" . I traced the source of the error back to the method I have shown above and found that using the computed property in the local scope of the method was causing the issue. Simply changing it to a stored property solved the issue.

But does anybody know why this happened? Why can't I use a computed property at the local method scope?

Comment: Compiler bug. You can't really reason with it 

Comment: Compiles fine for me in Swift 3.1 (after adding a `categories` variable) – could you please provide a [mcve]? But regardless, the compiler should never crash, so you should [file a bug report](https://bugs.swift.org/) with the aforementioned self-contained example.

Comment: @Hamish i just updated the example code to mirror my code more exactly

Comment: @MikeG Still compiling fine for me – although you omitted the definition `doSomething(dict:)`.